# OpenGL: Rotar triangulo sobre su centro

Tags: c++, opengl, glm, glsl

estroy tratando de rotar varios triangulos sobre su propio centro en C++, usando la libreria glm para hacer las transformaciones, el problema que tengo es que rota pero hace un efecto extraño. La idea es un triangulo de sierpinski donde algunos roten sobre su propio centro.

Este código hace que los triangulos roten, pero tambien se trasladan, no se quedan en el lugar:

```
    else{
        vertices.push_back(X);
        vertices.push_back(Y);
        vertices.push_back(Z);

        ourShader.use();
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Point), vertices.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);       
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3* sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); 
               
        glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(1.0f); 
        trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(-Y.x, -Y.y, -Y.z));      
        trans = glm::rotate(trans, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(Y.x, Y.y, Y.z));
        
        unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "transform");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(trans)); 

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
        vertices.clear();
    }
```

sin embargo si cambio esta parte del código:

```
trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(-Y.x, -Y.y, -Y.z));      
trans = glm::rotate(trans, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(Y.x, Y.y, Y.z));
```

por esta:

```
trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(Y.x, Y.y, Y.z));      
trans = glm::rotate(trans, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(-Y.x, -Y.y, -Y.z));
```

funciona correctamente (notese que se cambio los signos en los vectores en la funcion translate).

¿Porque de una forma no funciona y la otra si?

No se supone que es lo mismo, uno lo mueve, lo rota, y lo devuelve a su lugar y otro lo lleva al centro, lo rota, y lo devuelve a su lugar.

El punto Y es el punto del medio de cada triangulo y Y.x es su distancia de el punto medio de la ventana.

Comment: Todo triangulo tiene un **baricentro** (algo así como un centro de masa) ese es el punto fijo para la rotación. Debes escribir una función que lo obtenga y hacer rotar tomando ese punto como centro.

Comment: Ya lo hice y obtengo el mismo resultado, si la primera vez que llamo a translate() todo es positivo, y la segunda vez es negativo funciona, pero de la otra manera no, lo que no entiendo es porque no funciona de la otra manera

Comment: Si el triangulo es escaleno vas a observar un desplazamiento vertical **aparente** dentro del contenedor que uses para la visualización. Necesitas crear un contenedor con ejes fijos y tamaño suficiente para mostrar el efecto, sin que se afecte posicionalmente. No percibo que controles el tamaño del contenedor y que centres en el punto de rotación. (Posiblemente me equivoco en la percepción anotada)

Comment: Los triangulos son equilateros

Comment: Arma el contenedor construyendo la circunferencia que contiene los tres vértices. (no necesitas dibujarla) Y, haces rotar alrededor del centro de esa circunferencia, que es justamente el baricentro. Como el contenedor está construido la rotación se va a presentar limpia.

Comment: Eso te permite ofrecer una solución general. **Tres puntos no colineales determinan una única circunferencia.** Al hacerla rotar (pero mostrando sólo el triangulo) no se van a provocar oscilaciones del contenedor.

Comment: Estaría bueno saber qué es XYZ. El orden de las transformaciones importa. Lo usual es escalar, luego rotar y trasladar. En OpenGL el orden de escritura es al revés: T * R * S. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/16721